# Changing my Portlet version in Liferay from 5.2.3 to 6.2

Tags: tomcat, migration, liferay, portlet

Actually In liferay-plugin-package.xml in my portlet i have

```
 <module-id>liferay/MyPortlet/1.0.0/war</module-id>
```

and

```
 <liferay-versions>
    <liferay-version>5.2.3</liferay-version>
 </liferay-versions>
```

I want to change them to 6.2. i did make my portal migration but portlets it says unavailable.

Comment: anything in the logfile?

Comment: nothing, in some cases i putted only the up version in the liferay-plugin-package.xml 6.2+ it says deploying.. but nothing happens